# Python lambda function rolling through pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, lambda

I have this dataframe

```
data = [45,18,35,42,58,101,10]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["value"])
```

I made a lambda function that just creates a new column in my dataframe with the natural logarithm of the current value and the last value

```
data['ln'] = data['value'].apply(lambda x: math.log(x/x[1]))
```

but i get the following error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: Looks like `x[1]` is causing this error. `x` represents a `float` from the `value` column, thus is not a iterable type on which you can call `[index]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in `.apply` is just going to be the float value in your `value` column, which is why the subscript fails. You can do the division quickly with `.div` on a `.shift`, and take the logarithm from there with `numpy`:

```
In [100]: df = pd.DataFrame({'value': range(5)})

In [101]: df['value'].div(df['value'].shift())
Out[101]:
0         NaN
1         inf
2    2.000000
3    1.500000
4    1.333333
Name: value, dtype: float64

In [102]: np.log(df['value'].div(df['value'].shift()))
Out[102]:
0         NaN
1         inf
2    0.693147
3    0.405465
4    0.287682
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the column "ln", you can do:

```py
data["ln"] = data["value"].apply(lambda x: math.log(x / data.iloc[-1]))
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
   value        ln
0     45  1.504077
1     18  0.587787
2     35  1.252763
3     42  1.435085
4     58  1.757858
5    101  2.312535
6     10  0.000000
```

---

Or use `np.log()`:

```py
data["ln"] = np.log(data["value"] / data["value"].iloc[-1])
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
   value        ln
0     45  1.504077
1     18  0.587787
2     35  1.252763
3     42  1.435085
4     58  1.757858
5    101  2.312535
6     10  0.000000
```